# Set date min value to always be 10 days before current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my date's `min` value to always be 10 days before the current date.

Meaning the user shouldn't be able to select a date, that's 10 days before the current date.

So far I figured this out in `javascript` but `jQuery` is also fine.

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10){
   dd='0'+dd
} 
 
if(mm<10){
  mm='0'+mm
} 

today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);
```

```html
<input id="datefield" type='date'/>
```

But if the 10 days exceed the month and continue into the previous month, it doesn't work.

```
var dd = today.getDate()-10; //Subtracting 10 days to current date
```

Comment: so use setDate()

Comment: You're better off using `const tenDaysAgo = Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 10`. `Date.prototype.getDate` doesn't work they way you think it does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate

Comment: var dateOffset = (24*60*60*1000) * 5; //5 days
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime() - dateOffset); is another option if you favor to go that way but me, i would absolutely use MOMENT.JS for all date and time in JS.